# In an auditorium a comperer announces and asks the audince to take their seats on the left side. What does it mean?

Tags: usage

In an auditorium the announcer asks the audience to be seated on the left side seats.  Doesnt it mean the left side of the audience??

Comment: No, "the left side" is ambiguous. You don't know if the speaker (if facing the audience) is referring to his own left or the left as the audience faces the stage.  A speaker who understands this simple fact will say "The left side of the auditorium *as you face the stage.*" or "... when facing the stage".

Comment: Isnt the left of the auditorium the left of the people on the stage facing the audience?

Comment: If your life depended on it, would you take the bet? It is ambiguous because it's human nature to be an imperfectly communicating animal; when native speakers are in conversation you will often hear them say "Do you mean my left or your left?"  There is no ISO standards body for auditorium side naming conventions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for a logical decision, and is not about learning English (the meaning of *left* is not discussed or disputed).

Answer (score 0):

In such circumstances, it is safe to assume that the announcer means the left side from the perspective of the audience. If the announcer does in fact mean their own left side, then they are not a very good announcer. The same situation arises in things like exercise classes. In such cases, the public speakers should (and usually do) make directional references from the audience's perspective.